# What is the difference between a PRF and a PRF+?

Tags: pseudo-random-function, terminology

What is the difference between a PRF and a PRF+?  I am understanding them to mean the same thing, but I imagine that is because I don't understand their differences.

The [IKE RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2409#section-3.2) defines a PRF as:

> This pseudorandom function (PRF) takes as input a secret, a seed, and
> an identifying label and produces an output of arbitrary length.

The [TLS 1.2 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-5) defines a PRF as:

> prf(key, msg) is the keyed pseudo-random function-- often a keyed
> hash function-- used to generate a deterministic output that
> appears pseudo-random.

The [IKEv2 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5996#section-2.13) defines a PRF as:

> The PRF is used for the construction of keying material for all of
> the cryptographic algorithms used in both the IKE SA and the Child
> SAs.

The [IKEv2 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5996#page-46) defines a PRF+ as:

> Since the amount of keying material needed
> may be greater than the size of the output of the PRF, the PRF is
> used iteratively.
> The term "prf+" describes a function that outputs a pseudorandom stream based on the inputs to a pseudorandom function called "prf".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IKEv2 uses the term `PRF` to refer to a negotiated keyed random-looking function (for example, possibly HMAC-SHA256).  IKEv2 uses the term `PRF+` to refer to a specific construction based on that underlying negotiated function, as defined in section 2.13:

```
prf+ is defined as:

prf+ (K,S) = T1 | T2 | T3 | T4 | ...

where:
T1 = prf (K, S | 0x01)
T2 = prf (K, T1 | S | 0x02)
T3 = prf (K, T2 | S | 0x03)
T4 = prf (K, T3 | S | 0x04)
...
```

The term `PRF+` has no generally accepted meaning outside of IKEv2.

Comment: Looks identical to HKDF-Expand.

Comment: Hi Poncho, thanks for the answer.  I am was nearly going to mark it as the right answer, but I'm still not sure I fully understand your answer.  I don't suppose you could dumb it down just a bit, write it to a target audience that isn't as well versed in crypto or college math?

Comment: Also, a follow on question:  Is it safe to understand IKEv2's definition of PRF+ and IKEv1/TLS's definition of PRF as to mean the same thing?  Are both simply each individual protocol's strategy to create a arbitrary length output which is always identical if starting with identical inputs?